# PHP: Select part of string (from to) and apply changes on it

Tags: php

I want a way to change part of string according to simple marks. for example:

```
$string = "I'm student (at JIC college), and I'm GENIUS.";
```

I want to select `at JIC college` or any words between brackets and change their color. (I know how to change their color). but how to select it change it then put it back. and how to do that even if I had more than 1 brackets.

```
$string = "I'm student (at JIC college), and I'm GENIUS (not really).";
```

Comment: what if you had nested parenthesis? Like parenthesis within each other?

Comment: Does `preg_replace()` do what you want?

Comment: @1337holiday even though I want to change what inside it like `(aaa (asddsd) asasd)` I want to change this `aaa (asddsd) asasd`... it's going to be hard isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `preg_replace` to achieve this.

```
$string = "I'm student (at JIC college), and I'm GENIUS (not really).";

$string = preg_replace('/\(([^\)]+)\)/', '<span style="color:#f00;">$1</span>', $string);
```

Unfortunately this example is a little unclear as your chosen encapsulation gets lost in the regex and needs escaping.  I'd use something other than brackets if you're into making your code clear!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$string = "I'm student (at JIC college), and I'm GENIUS (not really).";

$pieces = explode("(", $string );

$result = explode(")", $pieces[1]);

echo $result[0]; // at JIC college
```

Answer (score 0):

Get String between () by this function

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}

$fullstring = "this is my [tag]dog[/tag]";
$parsed = get_string_between($fullstring, "[tag]", "[/tag]");

echo $parsed; // (result = dog)
```

and change the color.

Answer (score -1):

You can achive this using regular expressions:

```
$colorized = preg_replace('/(\(.*?\))/m', '<span style="color:#f90;">($1)</span>', $string);
```

Comment: @CORRUPT if you look carefully enough you'll notice that it wasn't requestet at the time when i wrote the answer. Anyway i am working on a solution therefore and i'll update this post as soon as it is ready